# Facing problem in including #include<curl/curl.h> in my C++ project, how to install the package for that

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Whenever I try to add a library(CURL) it shows a error "cannot open source file'curl/curl.h'" in visual Studio but installed Curl package using VcPkg .

I tried installing the package ,it shows package was installed but couldn't use it in the code

Comment: *Where* is libcurl installed? Perhaps you need to update your projects build-settings to point out the location of the header and library files?

Answer (score 1):

A wild guess: you have installed the package with vcpkg but not enabled the integration with visual studio.

You need to run "vcpkg integrate install" after the package is installed to add the include & library paths to visual studio.

See: https://vcpkg.io/en/getting-started.html

If that does not work, try restarting visual studio.